# How can I override the global variable in XSLT from a template?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not able to override a global variable in XSLT from template.

Global variable declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="abc" />
```

Template in which I wish to override global variable:

```
<xsl:template name ="newTemplate">     
    <xsl: variable name="abc" select="'1'" />
    <!- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Is it possible to override the global variable?  If so, how?**

Comment: Variables in XSLT are immutable in XSLT and cannot be changed once set. In your code snippet about, the declaration of `abc` in the template is said to "shadow" the global declaration. This means the global declaration won't be accessible in the template. You have just created a new variable with the same name, that is local to the template. To help you more, it might be better for you to describe what problem you are actually trying to solve, rather than how you are trying to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC: That comment is worth elevating to an answer, whether or not it addresses the X of an XY problem.

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've just rolled back the image to the previous version, which did actually show the code. @ISHAN SHARMA - You can format code samples in question simply by highlighting the code, and clicking the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: And I've fixed the formatting and countered the downvote, which downvoter might also want to reverse.  This should now be helpful to future readers.

Comment: the short answer is you can't. XSLT is not an imperative language, you can't do imperative things like mutate state. Consider moving the part of template A that defines the value into template C and use that in both A and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in XSLT are immutable in XSLT and cannot be changed once set. In the code snippet in your question, the declaration of `abc` in the template is said to "shadow" the global declaration. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-shadows).

This means the global declaration won't be accessible in the template. You have just created a new variable with the same name, that is local to the template.

This doesn't mean you cannot solve your underlying problem, just that you can't do it by means of changing variables. Ideally you should always the problem you are trying to solve, rather than just how you are trying to solve it.

Comment: @ISHANSHARMA: This completely answers the question you pose here.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer, and post a new question that includes a [mcve] so that we can provide more specific help so you can find an alternative way to solve your problem.   Thanks.